# Large Scale Application in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js. As per documentation Angular js is used to develop single page application. My question is that, can we develop large scale application using angular js.
Here my means to large scale application is shopping sites, social networking sites etc.

Many Thanks,

M.

Comment: I think pluralsight.com is developed with angular

Comment: Gabe , My first question is :can we develop large scale application in angular js

Comment: Yes you can. Look at this site. https://builtwith.angularjs.org/

Comment: U can develop large scale applications with native javascript, too. We building a large APP for internal use and if you start to build big apps with angularjs, you need to have some exp. with the architecture and stuff. 
We had an offshore workin on the frontend before and they were just deep diving every pitfall caused to make the SPA unuseable due to performance and memory leaks. 
I would recommend to rapid programm a prototype and play around before touching large apps.

Comment: BBC Live event coverage (Sochi 2014) is built using AngularJS see http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/internet/posts/Building-BBC-Live.

Comment: At Enplug we've built our entire management tool using AngularJS backed by a C# RESTful API. It's been a dream to work with. https://enplug.com. We're happy to answer any questions if anybody out there is evaluating AngularJS for large-scale use.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a developer working for a startup and I've recently moved to `AngularJS`. I've delivered my first 3 projects in the last 3 months, which were medium-scale applications with a lot of complex `api` interaction (one of the projects involved online ordering, payments).

The project I'm currently working on is of massive proportions and I've chosen `AngularJS` for the task. I think if you know how to use views correctly and write reusable modules right from the word go, its convincing to know that `AngularJS` is perfectly capable of doing anything you would want.

Of course – that means that instead of having one point of development for an application, you have to work on the backend/api design and tie it up with a *separate* application on the browser. But in the light of modern web-apps where you can use the same `api` to serve multiple platforms (mobiles, etc.) it turns out to be a blessing in disguise.

I strongly recommend `AngularJS`.

Comment: Can you please provide any link so i can explore. Thanks in aDvance

Comment: While the products I worked on aren't public (yet) I found a decent resource: https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw and this should convince you.

Comment: I think this is developed in YII framework using jquery not angular js.No angular directive used here

Comment: I meant reading through that article. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a tool for shipment acquisition for a medium sized shipping contractor.

The application is quite complex and large scaled. While I stumbled over some difficulties in the early days of development and planning, I managed to make the process very comfortable with growing experience.

I would argue that the key to success here is widespread knowledge of the frameworks capabilities.

This was my first AngularJS project and I failed to make use of all the features I was offered. Directives seemed to complex, I could not wrap my head around the basic workflow of an Angular application.

if you are willing to learn about your tools, you will definetly get rewared with a very natural and intuitive way of fabricating your project. My application scales very good and I was even able to extract some of its modules into separate, reusable parts that are now used within two other, albeit less-complex applications.

As Konstantin Krass correctly points out in the comments above, it would be helpful to play around a little with a prototype project in the beginning.